# Can you remove the 'Additional to:from the e-mail page layout or ise it in a validation rule?

Tags: email

We are not able to use the relay function so I am using validation rules for the TO:, CC: and BC: fields to enforce using our domain only.  I am not able to find the Additional To for use in a validation rule nor can I find it on the e-mail page layout so I can remove it.

Comment: what object are you writing the Validation Rules on?

Comment: the e-mail object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send an Email, the form's `To:` (a Contact's email) and `Additional To:` (text) are concatenated together in the `EmailMessage` object in field `ToAddress` separated by semi colon

```
SELECT ToAddress FROM EmailMessage where createddate = today
```

Here's an example value of `ToAddress`

- where fred@ent1541.com was the email's Contact
- where foo@bar.com was the `additional to`

  ```
  fred@ent1541.com; foo@bar.com
  ```

So your validation rule should probably be something of the form "Either the To or Additional To address must be xxx@mycompany.com"

Comment: That is the ptoblem - Additional To in not available.  I turned in a support tiicket in Monday and they are trying to find an expert to help me.

Comment: @user5728777 ?? whatever the user enters in additional To is concatenated to the contact's email and saved in `EmailMessage.ToAddress` so you can write validation rule on that field and cover both fields on the form

Comment: I am not trying to be obtuse - My validation rule blocks as it should n the To - does not block on the additional to -

Comment: Validation Rule Detail 
Rule Name To_Address_only_domain
Error Condition Formula AND(
 NOT(CONTAINS( ToAddress , domain.com')))
Error Message You can only send e-mails thought the xxxx domain

Comment: using workbench here is the concatenated To address - it allowed the foobar

Comment: you'll need a `REGEX` as you have to make sure that there exists a pattern `...@xxxx` that is not `@mycompany.com`

Comment: Perfect -Regex did it - thank you so much!

Comment: @user5728777 -- cool; as a favor to the community mark the answer above to indicate resolved